# Upgrade From WinForms to Telerik

Tags: winforms, telerik, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade WinForms to Telerik Controls and when I am upgrading this

```
this.treeAccounting.AfterSelect += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventHandler(this.TreeAccountingAfterSelect);
```

To this new RadControl Statement:

```
this.treeAccounting.SelectedNode += new Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTreeViewEventArgs(this.TreeAccountingAfterSelect);
```

I get an error about best overloaded method match having invalid arguments for the TreeAccountingAfterSelect. Also it says cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTreeNode'. Here is the function event for TreeAccountingAfterSelect.

```
private void TreeAccountingAfterSelect(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        string strSelectedNode = treeAccounting.SelectedNode.Text;

        // Since the user can select any node (root, branch, leaf) of a tree in any order -
        // cannot presume that they will select a root, then a leaf - so handle accordingly.
        if (treeRootNames[(int)TreeNodes.TrialBalance] == strSelectedNode)
        {
            // Configure the Generator for doing a Trial Balance (detail) report
            CrntReport = ReportTypes.TrialBalance;
            CrntLocation = Locations.UNKNOWN;

            // Based on default settings in the Report Property dialog (from App.Config) initialize
            // screen controls.
            lblCurrency.Visible = rptProperties.TBShowCurrencyCodes;
            cboxCurrencyCode.Visible = rptProperties.TBShowCurrencyCodes;
            this.Refresh();

            // Setup the selections for the various parameters in the TrialBalance
            // Parameters group.
            SetupTBControls();
        }
        return;
    }
```

I'm new to Telerik and I have tried different events and tried changing the parameter passed through the function and for some reason it isn't letting me use it like the WinForms. Can someone tell me where I am not understanding the change in WinForms to Telerik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [their documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/allmembers_t_telerik_wincontrols_ui_radtreeviewelement.html) it seems that there is no `SelectedNode` event for a RadTreeView.
Instead you have

```
SelectedNodeChanged     Occurs when selected node has been changed.  

SelectedNodeChanging    Occurs when the selected node is changing
```

And you don't use the `RadTreeViewEventArgs` to bind the event handler but a `RadTreeViewEventHandler`

So perhaps you need to write

```
this.treeAccounting.SelectedNodeChanged += 
      new RadTreeViewEventHandler(this.TreeAccountingAfterSelect);
```

The syntax for delegate will allow also

```
this.treeAccounting.SelectedNodeChanged += this.TreeAccountingAfterSelect;
```

Comment: Thank you that worked I thought I had tried that already and I must not have change the function side to RadControls that was bothering me for the last couple hours. I would give upvotes but I need 15 rep to be able to do that :/